# Compression plugin with Laravel mix

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack

I want to generate compressed resources files (br, or gz) after npm run prod with laravel.

My (simplified) webpack.mix.js (about the same with mix.styles too) :

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.options({
    cleanCss: {
        level: {
            1: {
                specialComments: 'none'
            }
        }
    },
    purifyCss: true
});


mix.scripts([
    'node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js',
    'resources/js/material/custom.js',
    'resources/js/material/waves.js',
    'node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js',
    'node_modules/laravel-echo/dist/echo.iife.js'
],'public/js/admin-all.js');

const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
       
        new CompressionPlugin({
            filename: '[path].br[query]',
            algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
            test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
            compressionOptions: { level: 11 },
            minRatio: 1,
            deleteOriginalAssets: false,
        }),
    ]
});
```

I want to generate .css.br .js.br ... next to the .css or .js files in public folder
But after **npm run prod**, no .br file generated.

*npm run prod ===> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js*

It output a mix.js.br file but I dont know where the source of this file is ??

How to do it ?

npm version : 6.12.1
node version : 12.13
os : Windows 10 pro x64

[image: Generated file, no .br but one strange mix.js.br]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use diretly broli compress with laravel mix.script or mix.styles,
the best way to do is to install :

```
npm install bread-compressor-cli -D
```

and edit your project package.json with this :

```
"prod": "npm run production && npm run compress",
"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"compress": "bread-compressor -s public/css/*.css public/js/*.js"
```

after just use npm run prod and it will run laravel mix (scripts concat) + brotli and gzip compress after. You can edit the compress script to follow your needs.

You can serve br and gzip files diretly to avoid compression on every request with apache/nginx, to save time and CPU !

Answer (score 0):

Your mix configuration looks alright.

Size of your assets are likely below the set [`threshold`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/compression-webpack-plugin#threshold) and that's why they are not being processed.

You may not need asset compression in your project if your assets are still less than 2KB.

As you mentioned adding to the end of your `webpack.mix.js`, I have assumed it to be the same with [the out of box one](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/webpack.mix.js#L14-L15).

Move the files to `resources/assets`. I say this because you refer to the need to still have them pre-processed.
Common practice in Laravel projects is to keep distribution ready assets in `public` folder.

The files now in `resources/assets` will need to be registered as components to be preprocessed  either using `js` or `css` or other [mix APIs](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/mixjs).

Note that you can register one or more [entrypoints](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) by successively calling mix API methods or using wildcards.

For example, to process all [Javascript files **via Webpack**](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/v5.0.0/src/components/Javascript.js) *separately* in `resources/assets/js`. One can write:

```js
mix.js('resources/assets/js/**/*.js', 'public/js');
```

> Mix API processes components either via Webpack, Babel, or a plain task.

`mix.scripts` is one of the APIs processing components using a [plain old task](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/v5.0.0/src/components/Combine.js#L48).

So long as none of your components are registered to be processed through Webpack, the compression plugin added in the Webpack configuration will not be applied.

Currently, `mix.js.br` is a left over from an hack in the mix project to satisfy the requirement for an entry in Webpack. See https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/v5.0.0/src/webpackPlugins/MockEntryPlugin.js

Comment: it's upper than the threashold ex I have a  528kB file, my assets are in public/css public/js

Comment: I udapted my answer, maybe a path problem ?
Something like : 
test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
include: /\/public/,

Comment: updated again with a full webpack.mix.js file, not a problem of laravel mix, I know how to use it.

Comment: @neoteknic See my latest update. I hope it further clarifies why your components are not processed and there is a `mix.js.br` output particularly in my link in the final paragraph.

Comment: thank you, so no way to use it with scripts, styles ? It's not possible to concat files and use css or js tools to minify, compress, etc... after the compilation ?

Comment: That is not correct. `mix` api allows for registering a sequence of tasks. You would  add to your already existing sequence of task ones to compile `js` and `css` files through `webpack`. Seeing that the output of combine task is already in `public/js/`.  Register that path as the entry point using `mix.js` and `mix.css`. You would however need to write the output of this process to another folder. I don't see why processed files should overwrite the originals.